# I have Multiple logical records in one db row, how do I split them into separate rows?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has data like:

| Name | Item_1 | Qty_1 | Price_1 | Item_2 | Qty_2 | Price_2 | ... | Item_50 | Qty_50 | Price_50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Apples | 10 | 0.50 | Pears | 5 | 0.65 | ... | Lemons | 12 | 0.25 |
| Alice | Cherries | 20 | 1.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I need to process the data per-item, so the ideal form of the data would be:

| Name | ItemNo | Item | Qty | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | Apples | 10 | 0.50 |
| Bob | 2 | Pears | 5 | 0.65 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Bob | 50 | Lemons | 12 | 0.25 |
| Alice | 1 | Cherries | 20 | 1.00 |

How can I convert between the two forms?

I have looked at the pivot command, but it seems to convert column names into data in a field, not split groups of columns into separate rows. It doesn't look like it will work for this application.

The current code looks something like:

```
( SELECT t1.Name, 1 AS ItemNo, t1.Item_1 AS Item, t1.Qty_1 AS Qty, t1.Price_1 AS Price FROM table t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.Name, 2 AS ItemNo, t2.Item_2 AS Item, t2.Qty_2 AS Qty, t2.Price_2 AS Price FROM table t2
  UNION ALL
  ...
  SELECT t50.Name, 50 AS ItemNo, t50.Item_50 AS Item, t50.Qty_50 AS Qty, t50.Price_50 AS Price FROM table t50
)
```

It works, but it seems hard to maintain. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

*Hopefully* the reason you want to do this is to fix your design. If not, then make the reason you're asking is to fix your design.

Anyway, one method is to use a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot the data:

```sql
SELECT YT.Name,
       V.ItemNo,
       V.Item,
       V.Qty,
       V.Price
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,YT.Item_1, YT.Qty_1, YT.Price1),
                        (2,YT.Item_2, YT.Qty_2, YT.Price2),
                        (3,YT.Item_3, YT.Qty_3, YT.Price3),
                        ... --You get the idea
                        (49,YT.Item_49, YT.Qty_49, YT.Price49),
                        (50,YT.Item_50, YT.Qty_50, YT.Price50))V(ItemNo,Item,Qty,Price)
WHERE V.Item IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The best I can do to fix the design is to convert the external table generated by someone else's system to something sensible when I import it into my database.

Comment: That *is* what a good ETL process does, @BlaisePascal .